# How do you delete a single row using the CSV module in Python?

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I was trying to create a log in and sign up portal using python. I aimed to delete an account if you have 3 failed log in attempts. All writer.writerow(row) does is either wipe the entire file or not do anything at all.

I even have a counter variable to count the number of failed log in attempts and I have a feeling that might not be working as I intended.

Any help would be appreciated.

````
import csv

#CSV

def csvsign():
    prof_name_text = str(prof_text.get())
    email_id_text = str(email_text.get())
    phone_no_text = str(phone_text.get())
    passw_name_text = str(passw_text.get())
    dob_name_text = str(dob_text.get())
    a = [prof_name_text, email_id_text, phone_no_text, passw_name_text, dob_name_text]
    print(a)
    with open('details.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_reader.writerow(a)
    output = tk.Label(master=sign_window, text='Congratulations, you have created an account!')
    output.grid(column = 0, row = 4)
    csv_file.close()
    sign_window.destroy()

def csvlog():
    email_id_text = str(email_text_log.get())
    passw_name_text = str(passw_text_log.get())
    global counter
    x = 0
    with open('details.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for line in csv_reader:
            if counter == 3:
                output = tk.Label(master=log_window, text='You have had too many failed login attempts. \nYour account is being deleted.')
                output.grid(column=0, row=4)
                if line['email_id'] == email_id_text:
                    x = line
                break
            else:
                if line['email_id'] == email_id_text:
                    if line['password'] == passw_name_text:
                        output = tk.Label(master=log_window, text='Congratulations, you have logged in!')
                        output.grid(column = 0, row = 4)
                    else:
                        counter += 1
                        output = tk.Label(master=log_window, text='Wrong password, please try again.')
                        output.grid(column=0, row=4)
                else:
                    output = tk.Label(master=log_window, text='Invalid email address, please try again.')
                    output.grid(column=0, row=4)
    if x != 0:
        imp =  open('details.csv', 'rb')
        out = open('details.csv', 'wb')
        writer = csv.writer(out)
        for row in csv.reader(imp):
            if row == x:
                writer.writerow(row)
        imp.close()
        out.close()

#GUI

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("400x400")

def sign_up():
    global sign_window
    sign_window = tk.Tk()
    sign_window.geometry("400x400")

    #Profile name
    prof_name = tk.Label(sign_window, text='Enter desired profile name:')
    prof_name.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
    global prof_text
    prof_text = tk.Entry(sign_window)
    prof_text.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

    #Email ID
    email_id = tk.Label(sign_window, text='Enter your Email ID:')
    email_id.grid(column = 0, row = 2)
    global email_text
    email_text = tk.Entry(sign_window)
    email_text.grid(column = 1, row = 2)

    #Phone number
    phone = tk.Label(sign_window, text='Enter your Phone Number:')
    phone.grid(column=0, row=3)
    global phone_text
    phone_text = tk.Entry(sign_window)
    phone_text.grid(column=1, row=3)

    #Password
    passw = tk.Label(sign_window, text='Enter your desired Password:')
    passw.grid(column=0, row=4)
    global passw_text
    passw_text = tk.Entry(sign_window)
    passw_text.grid(column=1, row=4)

    #Date of birth
    dob = tk.Label(sign_window, text='Enter your Date of Birth in dd/mm/yy format:')
    dob.grid(column=0, row=5)
    global dob_text
    dob_text = tk.Entry(sign_window)
    dob_text.grid(column=1, row=5)

    #Submit Button
    sub_but = tk.Button(sign_window, text = 'Submit', command = csvsign)
    sub_but.grid(column = 1, row = 6)

    sign_window.mainloop()

def log_in():
    global counter
    counter = 0
    global log_window
    log_window = tk.Tk()
    log_window.geometry('400x400')

    #E-mail
    email_id = tk.Label(log_window, text='Enter your Email ID:')
    email_id.grid(column=0, row=1)
    global email_text_log
    email_text_log = tk.Entry(log_window)
    email_text_log.grid(column=1, row=1)

    #Password
    passw = tk.Label(log_window, text='Enter your Password:')
    passw.grid(column=0, row=2)
    global passw_text_log
    passw_text_log = tk.Entry(log_window)
    passw_text_log.grid(column=1, row=2)

    #Log in button
    log_but = tk.Button(log_window, text= 'Log in', command = csvlog)
    log_but.grid(column = 1, row = 3)
    log_window.mainloop()

intro = tk.Label(text = "Good Morning! \nPlease sign up if you haven't already. \nIf you have an account, please log in.")
intro.grid()

button1 = tk.Button(text='Sign Up', command = sign_up)
button1.grid()

button2 = tk.Button(text='Log in', command = log_in)
button2.grid()

window.mainloop()```
````

Comment: So, you would just need to know someone's username to get his/her account deleted?

Comment: Suhas, would you accept solutions using pandas? It's so much easier working with csv with it.

Comment: I assume this is for practice but in the off chance that this is for some project you really want to use, I recommend not storing user information (username and passwords) in a csv file... Also you should not be using `global` in your code.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? Such as the code you use to work with the csv? and a simple csv to use as an example?

Comment: @oppressionslayer no, don't use pandas for this. the csv module is perfectly usable for working with csv files.

Comment: In any case, of course when you use the writer it's wiping the file, you open your file using `open('details.csv', 'wb')` mode, *which will truncate a file if it exists* then open it for reading.

Comment: Also, can you post one line of the csv, this helps me know exactly what i'm working with. thx!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete only one row in CSV with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987312/how-to-delete-only-one-row-in-csv-with-python)