# Python and CSV read data from a specific row choosen by the user

Tags: python, csv

I'm doing a python script that reads a CSV file. This is the code:

```
with open("DATABASE.csv", "r", newline="") as a:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(a)
    rows = list(csv_reader)
    print(rows[2]["NAME"] rows[2]["SURNAME"])
```

The `[2]` means that it read the second line of the file.

How can I replace it with a number chosen by the user?
If I save the user's choice into a variable and I insert the variable in the `[ ]` it reply with `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

*--*

And other little thing: is there a way to delete a single line in the CSV?

Comment: _"is there a way to delete a single line in the CSV"_: Read the whole CSV to a list, remove the row you want to from your list, and write all rows back to the file. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987312/how-to-delete-only-one-row-in-csv-with-python). Also read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) The answers you seek already exist on Stack Overflow, and [google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=is+there+a+way+to+delete+a+single+line+in+the+CSV)

Answer (score -1):

`input()` return a string, so you have to cast it to integer, change the input code with `int(input())`.

If you want to delete a single line on the csv file just modify the list that contains the csv file, in your case the `rows` variable, and then save it back to csv file.

Comment: Thanks! Now however it says me that "IndexError: list index out of range", but if I write only the string "print(rows[1]["NAME"]....) it works.

Comment: Nice! if this help you i would appreciate if you upvote this answer :)