# How to remove a specific row from a CSV file in Python

Tags: python

How can i remove one row from CSV?

```
user1,user2
user2,user3
```

i have this csv file and i need to delete only first row.

```
import csv

with open("info.csv", "w") as file:
 for line in file:
     f.writerow(line)
```

Comment: please provide an example of what you tried to do to solve this problem.
what is the expected result?

Comment: Showing an example CSV file would be useful.

Comment: Or if you need to delete a specific _pattern_: [How to delete only one row in CSV with python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56987312/2745495)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't. Instead, you create a new file with the row skipped.

```py
import csv

with open("info.csv", "r") as read_file, open("info2.csv", "w") as write_file:
    reader = csv.reader(read_file)
    writer = csv.writer(write_file)
    next(reader)  # Skip the first row
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('info.csv') 
df = df.iloc[1: , :] # Drop first row
df.to_csv('info.csv')
```